# Basis of Generalized Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading through my notes on generalized eigenvectors and I understand that the intuition behind their definition is to allow us to find eigenbases of all linear operators. By the spectral theorems we know that Normal and self-adjoint operators have an eigenbasis under C and R respectively.

My question is do all operators have a basis of generalized eigenvectors? My text states that the answer is yes without providing an explanation. It is, since every eigenvector is a generalized eigenvector, that each operator has an eigenbasis so therefore a generalized eigenbasis must exist? I feel that I am missing something simple here

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: Ah, seeing as this is the last section of the chapter I believe he must be building to these results but simply mentioning it now